# Broyden's method implementation in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to write an implementation of the Broyden method in Python. I have an example in Matlab, trying to rewrite it but unsuccessfully.
+A is the Jacobian matrix
F - 4 eloquent matrix:

```matlab
function F=f(X)
 F(1)=X(1)+2*X(2)+X(3)+4*X(4)-20.7;
 F(2)=X(1)^2+2*X(1)*X(2)+X(4)^3-15.88;
 F(3)=X(1)^3+X(3)^2+X(4)-21.218;
 F(4)=3*X(2)+X(3)*X(4)-7.9;
 F=F(:);

for iii=1:itmax 
    deltax=-A\f(x);

    x=x+deltax; fi1=f(x); 
    %A=A+(fi1-fi-A*deltax)*deltax'/(deltax'*deltax);
    a1 = A*deltax;
    a2 = fi1-fi;
    a3 = a2-a1;
    a4 = a3*deltax';
    a5 = deltax'*deltax;
    a6 = a4/a5;
    A=A+a6;

    tikslumas=norm(deltax)/(norm(x)+norm(deltax));

    if tikslumas < eps
        fprintf(1,'\n x ='); fprintf(1,'  %g',x);
        fprintf(1,'\n  f ='); fprintf(1,'  %g',f(x));
        break
    elseif iii == itmax
        fprintf(1,'\n ****failed: x ='); fprintf(1,'  %g',x);
        fprintf(1,'\n  f ='); fprintf(1,'  %g',f(x));
        break
fi=fi1;
end
```

I am trying to do the same in Python:

```py
for i in range(1, itmax):
    deltax,resid,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, f(x))
    for j in range(len(deltax)):
        deltax[j] = -deltax[j]
    for j in range(len(deltax)):
        x[j] = x[j] + deltax[j]        
    fi1=f(x);
    deltaxT = np.matrix(deltax).T
    a1 = np.multiply(A, deltax)
    a1 = a1.sum(axis=1)
    a2 = np.subtract(fi1,fi)
    a3 = np.subtract(a2,a1)
    a4 = np.multiply(a3,deltaxT)
    a4 = np.matrix(a4).T
    a5 = (np.multiply(deltax,deltax)).sum(axis=0) #???? gal???
    a6 = np.divide(a4,a5)
    A=A+a6;
```

But the result after 3-4 for cycle aren't the same and final result is totally different

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, are you aware of [`scipy.optimize.broyden1`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.broyden1.html)? (And [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.root-broyden1.html))

Comment: I know this function, but the task is to implement this method